# Monitoring kibana transaction through APM

Tags: kibana, elastic-apm

I want to monitor kibana internal transaction through elastic-apm. I am confuse how can i do this. I am following this [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/kibana-debugging.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution you can found in here https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/151253